# Schema markup for product categories and subcategories - how to?

Tags: seo, schema.org, ecommerce

I've been wondering about which Schema should I use for an e-commerce site of one of my clients' website. Can't show proper code and sensitive information, but I'll try to explain what I've been thinking about.

Right here: https://inchoo.net/online-marketing/schema-markup-for-ecommerce-websites/

The author says that for category pages I should use ItemList Schema

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
 {
 "@context":"http://schema.org",
 "@type":"ItemList",
 "ItemListElement":
 [
   {
  "@type":"ListItem",
   "position":0,
   "url":"https://www.example.com/ankle-boots-ana.html"
  },
   {
   "@type":"ListItem",
   "position":1,
   "url":"https://www.example.com/ankle-boots-clara.html"
   },
   {
   "@type":"ListItem",
   "position":2,
   "url":"https://www.example.com/ankle-boots-maria.html"
   }
  ]
 }
</script>
```

Does anyone have an example of how it would look? For example, if I have a category with electric guitars with 5 subcategories that contain certain electric guitar models which would be listed in the schema ListItem. Is that the best schema type for this instance?

Second question - when it comes to subcategories, should I use ItemList Schema?

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "ItemList",
    "url": "https://www.myexamplestore.com/products/",
    "numberOfItems": "2",
    "itemListElement": [
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": {
              "@type": "Product",
                  "image": "https://www.myexamplestore.com/product-one/image.jpg",
                  "url": "https://www.myexamplestore.com/products/#productone",
                  "name": "Product One",
                  "offers": {
                      "@type": "Offer",
                      "price": "13.00",
                      "priceCurrency": "USD",
                      "url": "https://www.myexamplestore.com/products/"
                  }
            }
          },
          {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 2,
            "item": {
              "@type": "Product",
                  "image": "https://www.myexamplestore.com/product-two/image.jpg",
                  "url": "https://www.myexamplestore.com/products/#producttwo",
                  "name": "Product Two",
                  "offers": {
                      "@type": "Offer",
                      "price": "12.00",
                      "priceCurrency": "USD",
                      "url": "https://www.myexamplestore.com/products/"
                  }
              }
          }
    ]
}
</script>
```

I know that it's a bit of a gray area for Google when it comes to adding product information on category pages - does that apply also for the subcategory pages?

I would be so thankful for Your help and guidance <3 Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Google supports the use of ItemList for their carousel feature. But that does not include Product lists at the moment:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/carousel

I don't know of any documented features they have for category pages. So no documented rich snippets you can get for those pages.

Your example looks mostly right if you decide to follow the carousel guidelines. The products are on a different page so they are correctly only listed as urls. The minor correctly I would make is position should start with 1.